# XML element to Map in Groovy. Using XMLSluper

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy

I want to convert my xml element  configurations in Groovy Map in which to put all conf elements in form
`Map<String, Map<String,String>>` where String is name of the conf-s elements, and in the value Map there are another attributes of current conf element ex.

```
map[0] = {one,[visivility:public,description:Configuration one.]

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bla-module version="2.0" >
    <configurations>
            <conf name="one" visibility="public" description="Configuration one."/>
            <conf name="two" visibility="private" description="Configuration two."/>
    </configurations>
</bla-module>
```

What is the fastest way to do trying to use groovy syntax and XMLSluper.
PS The number of the attributes in conf-s elements are unknown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try (I'm not at a computer to verify):

```
new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )
                .configurations
                .conf
                .collectEntries { c->
                    [ c.@name, c.attributes() ]
                }
```

Comment: Don't work with XmlSluper but with XmlParser works. So I will accept this solution. GREAT, Thanks, tim.

Comment: @Xelian Odd...  Just got to a computer, and tried with XmlSlurper and it works for me... Glad you got it working though :-)

Comment: @Xelian Oh, and if you don't want `name` in the internal map as well as being the main key, then you can do `[ c.@name, c.attributes().findAll { it.key != 'name' } ]` :-)